# How to enable this so I can require sign in?

Tags: windows-10, security, passwords, sleep, login

[image]

This morning I came to work with a "surprise", that my computer didn't lock automatically, though I thought I configured it to do so.

Then I went through everything just want to make sure. I found that this is greyed out.
Does that mean my laptop might have "woke up" itself and logged on?????

How do I enable the option so I can change this ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in windows 10 build 1709. You can try upgrading it.

You can lower your UAC settings. Your UAC settings can prevent you from doing this. Also you can open gpedit.msc and go to 
Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Power Management > Sleep Settings and enable Require password when waking up from sleep.

Or also if your computer is running on mains power then use in command prompt `powercfg /SETACVALUEINDEX SCHEME_CURRENT SUB_NONE CONSOLELOCK 1` and if your laptop `powercfg /SETDCVALUEINDEX SCHEME_CURRENT SUB_NONE CONSOLELOCK 1` these are different because laptop runs on DC current and desktop computers run on AC current.

Comment: I am using 20H1 version, which is 2004.19041.329

Answer (score 0):

Check your settings for Suspending. They may have changed. Make sure the setting includes also requiring password to start up.

If you are on V1709, you need to upgrade Windows. V1709 is out of support, and V2004 is out. If there was a bug in V1709, I do not think it was too wide spread.

For sure, do a full scan with Windows Defender for malware.

Comment: I am using 2004 version.

Comment: Please check the other two suggestions I offered.

Comment: It's a full/fresh install. Not sure what Suspending has to do with it? What exactly am I looking for?

Comment: Check all your relevant settings - Sign in settings and power / display settings. Something may have gone wrong in the fresh install.  Use the computer manufacturer's Driver Update App to update all drivers.